# how to select from nested table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a T-SQL statement that is trying to get a percentage using a static sum.

Here's an example

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col1/b.col2Sum FROM (
    Select SUM(col2) FROM (
         Select col1, col2 FROM SomeTable
    ) As a
) as b
```

This doesn't execute and tells me a is an invalid object. How can I ether get to that nested table, or 2 make a static sum to use instead of table b?

Although in this example col1, and 2 are simple statements, assume that they are semi-complex aggregations instead of simple select columns.

Edited example to match answer:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, col4/(SELECT SUM(col4) FROM U) as uPercent FROM(
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM SomeTable) as U
```

I get Invalid object name U

Also, just to be clear, in the outer query, i cant just select col1, col2 etc from SomeTable, because those columns are aggregates and complex logic.

Comment: Could you explain, in plain language what your expecting to get out of the query? If I knew, then perhaps I can help you write it correctly.

Comment: As is, it can't work. Try and execute them separately and you'll see why. The middle query only has 1 column. col1 and col2 are not visible on the outer level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate a percentage on the total of a column then you can do it with a subquery... something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
  col1/(
    SELECT SUM(col2)
    FROM SomeTable
  )
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: this seemed to get me much closer, but im still having one issue, explained above in the edit.

Comment: The error message you got is telling you all you need to know. You can't use the alias in the subquery. I didn't use it... and there's a reason ;)

Comment: Any alternative then, i cant(or it would be obnoxious and unclean to) use SomeTable in my main query.... any work around to where i can get the sum of a column on my subquery, and then use that as a static variable in which to do percentages with?

Comment: You could pull it in with a full outer join with no join condition... which is not clean, and probably also very inefficient. Maybe you could use CTE... but I'm not much into that to help you. It's probably best you add some details as to why you can't. It is standard practice to reference the same table in different parts of an SQL statement if the result construction requires it.

Comment: Alright well in that case ill set the sum to a variable. Thats the best compromise i can think of.